# What is the simplest way to send data to a tape library?

Tags: backup, block-device, archive, tape

I am looking for the simplest (feasible) way to push data away on a tape library. This is for archiving finalized, immutable datasets that only need to be retrieved in case of a catastrophic failure of another storage system out of our reach.

If I was operating on the level of a single tape, I would write a simple script to do some bookkeeping on the file positions on the tape, and just append with tar. Unfortunately, I am not dealing with a single tape, but a 48 tapes library (IBM Tape Library System Storage TS3100) and datasets that will mostly span at least 2 tapes (ca. 10TB per dataset) - and I don't really how that thing works, except for having read the man page for mtx.

Is it feasible to work with `tar -M --new-volume-script ...`, and have it note down tape and file number or am I missing something here? Is there an even simpler way, or can anybody recommend a simple backup software that already does what I want?